# Split matrix by all-zero columns

Tags: matrix

Below is my input:

```
mat = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

$\quad\quad\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

I would like to split this matrix by the columns with all-zeros, and in the process remove those columns from the matrix. Expected output below:

[image: output]

Comment: Please add a code sample not a latex version. And try `Transpose /@ (SplitBy[m\[Transpose], 
    MatchQ[#, {0 ..}] &] /. {{0 ..} ..} -> Sequence[])`

Comment: @Kuba Nice to see you post something again!

Comment: @Pickett Thanks :) that's nice of you, I will try to fully come back around october. I have a lot of boring stuff to do know :/

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised MMA doesn't have something like [`StringSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) for list, but maybe I haven't looked hard enough. I added the `..` to delete multiple all-zero columns after seeing @Kuba's comment. Please upvote his comment instead of my answer since his was the more succinct.

```
mat = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}};

MatrixForm@Transpose@# & /@ 
 DeleteCases[SplitBy[Transpose@mat, # != {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} &], {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}..}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the same idea as seismatica's answer, but with different details.

```
m =
  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
   {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
   {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
   {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}};

split =
  Transpose /@
    DeleteCases[
      SplitBy[If[Plus @@ # > 0, #] & /@ Transpose[m], # === Null &], 
      {Null}];
```

A different approach using `Reap` and `Sow`.

```
split = 
  Module[{tag = 1}, 
    Transpose /@ Last @ Reap[If[Plus @@ # > 0, Sow[#, tag], tag++] & /@ Transpose[m]]]
```

Both of the above produce

```
MatrixForm /@ split
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of *Mathematica* 10 I would have written it like this:

```
Composition[
  DeleteCases[{{0} ..}],
  Map[Transpose],
  SplitBy[#, Unitize@*Total] &,
  Transpose
  ]@mat
```

> `{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0}, {1}, {0},
>   {0}, {1}, {1}}, {{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}, {1}}}`

With rules I would write:

```
Transpose /@ {Transpose[mat] //. {el__, {0 ..}, rest___} :> Sequence[{el}, {rest}]}
```

> `{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0}, {1}, {0},
>   {0}, {1}, {1}}, {{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}, {1}}}`

The first method assumes numeric matrix elements but the second doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function hopefully with some amount of reusability:

```
splitColsByMask[base_, mask_, key_: 1] := 
  base[[All, #]] & /@ Split[Pick[Range@Length@mask, mask, key], #2 - 1 == # &]
```

A "mask" for your input:

```
v = Unitize @ Total @ Unitize @ mat
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}
> ```

Applied:

```
MatrixForm /@ splitColsByMask[mat, v]
```

[image]

The third parameter "key" defaults to `1`; it is the "take" pattern for `Part`.